# Removing of artificial sampling step effects

Tags: fitting

Look at this plot, it represents an underground interface between two formations, this interface should dip very gently left-downward, all the steps are artificial effects due to sampling. The natural slope of this curve is very important to me, for example, if a seismic ray happens to incident at the joint of step, then the refection path is totally wrong. I have tried methods of spline interpolation, moving average, etc, somehow I am not satisfactory with the results, some methods alter the general location of the curve. It might be better to let the end points of the curve be fixed. It might work if I resample the data, but it takes too much efforts and you may need to resample differently for different interface curves. Could someone show me how to efficiently get rid of these step artificials? Data is attached below (two interfaces, if you method works on both interfaces, then it works). Thanks a lot!

(*Note: both the horizontal and vertical sampling interval is 20 feet, the general slope of this interface should be about 1 degree, but at the steps, the slope is about 45 degree!*)

[image]

```
curve1={{62700,-2460},{62720,-2460},{62740,-2460},{62760,-2460},{62780,-2460},{62800,-2460},{62820,-2460},{62840,-2460},{62860,-2460},{62880,-2460},{62900,-2460},{62920,-2460},{62940,-2460},{62960,-2460},{62980,-2460},{63000,-2460},{63020,-2460},{63040,-2460},{63060,-2460},{63080,-2460},{63100,-2460},{63120,-2460},{63140,-2460},{63160,-2460},{63180,-2460},{63200,-2440},{63220,-2440},{63240,-2440},{63260,-2440},{63280,-2440},{63300,-2440},{63320,-2440},{63340,-2440},{63360,-2440},{63380,-2440},{63400,-2440},{63420,-2440},{63440,-2440},{63460,-2440},{63480,-2440},{63500,-2440},{63520,-2440},{63540,-2440},{63560,-2440},{63580,-2440},{63600,-2440},{63620,-2440},{63640,-2440},{63660,-2440},{63680,-2440},{63700,-2440},{63720,-2440},{63740,-2440},{63760,-2440},{63780,-2440},{63800,-2440},{63820,-2440},{63840,-2440},{63860,-2420},{63880,-2420},{63900,-2420},{63920,-2420},{63940,-2420},{63960,-2420},{63980,-2420},{64000,-2420},{64020,-2420},{64040,-2420},{64060,-2420},{64080,-2420},{64100,-2420},{64120,-2420},{64140,-2420},{64160,-2420},{64180,-2420},{64200,-2420},{64220,-2420},{64240,-2420},{64260,-2420},{64280,-2420},{64300,-2420},{64320,-2420},{64340,-2420},{64360,-2420},{64380,-2420},{64400,-2420},{64420,-2420},{64440,-2400},{64460,-2400},{64480,-2400},{64500,-2400},{64520,-2400},{64540,-2400},{64560,-2400},{64580,-2400},{64600,-2400},{64620,-2400},{64640,-2400},{64660,-2400},{64680,-2400},{64700,-2400},{64720,-2400},{64740,-2400},{64760,-2400},{64780,-2400},{64800,-2400},{64820,-2400},{64840,-2400},{64860,-2400},{64880,-2400},{64900,-2400},{64920,-2400},{64940,-2400},{64960,-2400},{64980,-2400},{65000,-2400},{65020,-2380},{65040,-2380},{65060,-2380},{65080,-2380},{65100,-2380},{65120,-2380},{65140,-2380},{65160,-2380},{65180,-2380},{65200,-2380},{65220,-2380},{65240,-2380},{65260,-2380},{65280,-2380},{65300,-2380},{65320,-2380},{65340,-2380},{65360,-2380},{65380,-2380},{65400,-2380},{65420,-2380},{65440,-2380},{65460,-2380},{65480,-2380},{65500,-2380},{65520,-2380},{65540,-2380},{65560,-2380},{65580,-2380},{65600,-2360},{65620,-2360},{65640,-2360},{65660,-2360},{65680,-2360},{65700,-2360},{65720,-2360},{65740,-2360},{65760,-2360},{65780,-2360},{65800,-2360},{65820,-2360},{65840,-2360},{65860,-2360},{65880,-2360},{65900,-2360},{65920,-2360},{65940,-2360},{65960,-2360},{65980,-2360},{66000,-2360},{66020,-2360},{66040,-2360},{66060,-2360},{66080,-2360},{66100,-2360},{66120,-2360},{66140,-2360},{66160,-2360},{66180,-2360},{66200,-2360},{66220,-2340},{66240,-2340},{66260,-2340},{66280,-2340},{66300,-2340},{66320,-2340},{66340,-2340},{66360,-2340},{66380,-2340},{66400,-2340},{66420,-2340},{66440,-2340},{66460,-2340},{66480,-2340},{66500,-2340},{66520,-2340},{66540,-2340},{66560,-2340},{66580,-2340},{66600,-2340},{66620,-2340},{66640,-2340},{66660,-2340},{66680,-2340},{66700,-2340},{66720,-2340},{66740,-2340},{66760,-2340},{66780,-2340},{66800,-2340},{66820,-2340},{66840,-2340},{66860,-2320},{66880,-2320},{66900,-2320},{66920,-2320},{66940,-2320},{66960,-2320},{66980,-2320},{67000,-2320},{67020,-2320},{67040,-2320},{67060,-2320},{67080,-2320},{67100,-2320},{67120,-2320},{67140,-2320},{67160,-2320},{67180,-2320},{67200,-2320},{67220,-2320},{67240,-2320},{67260,-2320},{67280,-2320},{67300,-2320},{67320,-2320},{67340,-2320},{67360,-2320},{67380,-2320},{67400,-2320},{67420,-2320},{67440,-2320},{67460,-2320},{67480,-2320},{67500,-2300},{67520,-2300},{67540,-2300},{67560,-2300},{67580,-2300},{67600,-2300},{67620,-2300},{67640,-2300},{67660,-2300},{67680,-2300},{67700,-2300},{67720,-2300},{67740,-2300},{67760,-2300},{67780,-2300},{67800,-2300},{67820,-2300},{67840,-2300},{67860,-2300},{67880,-2300},{67900,-2300},{67920,-2300},{67940,-2300},{67960,-2300},{67980,-2300},{68000,-2300},{68020,-2300},{68040,-2300},{68060,-2300},{68080,-2300},{68100,-2300},{68120,-2300},{68140,-2280},{68160,-2280},{68180,-2280},{68200,-2280},{68220,-2280},{68240,-2280},{68260,-2280},{68280,-2280},{68300,-2280},{68320,-2280},{68340,-2280},{68360,-2280},{68380,-2280},{68400,-2280},{68420,-2280},{68440,-2280},{68460,-2280},{68480,-2280},{68500,-2280},{68520,-2280},{68540,-2280},{68560,-2280},{68580,-2280},{68600,-2280},{68620,-2280},{68640,-2280},{68660,-2280},{68680,-2280},{68700,-2280},{68720,-2280},{68740,-2280},{68760,-2280},{68780,-2260},{68800,-2260},{68820,-2260},{68840,-2260},{68860,-2260},{68880,-2260},{68900,-2260},{68920,-2260},{68940,-2260},{68960,-2260},{68980,-2260},{69000,-2260},{69020,-2260},{69040,-2260},{69060,-2260},{69080,-2260},{69100,-2260},{69120,-2260},{69140,-2260},{69160,-2260},{69180,-2260},{69200,-2260},{69220,-2260},{69240,-2260},{69260,-2260},{69280,-2260},{69300,-2260},{69320,-2260},{69340,-2260},{69360,-2260},{69380,-2260},{69400,-2260},{69420,-2260},{69440,-2260},{69460,-2260},{69480,-2260},{69500,-2260},{69520,-2260},{69540,-2260},{69560,-2260},{69580,-2260},{69600,-2260},{69620,-2260},{69640,-2260},{69660,-2260},{69680,-2260},{69700,-2260},{69720,-2240},{69740,-2240},{69760,-2240},{69780,-2240},{69800,-2240},{69820,-2240},{69840,-2240},{69860,-2240},{69880,-2240},{69900,-2240},{69920,-2240},{69940,-2240},{69960,-2240},{69980,-2240},{70000,-2240},{70020,-2240},{70040,-2240},{70060,-2240},{70080,-2240},{70100,-2240},{70120,-2240},{70140,-2240},{70160,-2240},{70180,-2240},{70200,-2240},{70220,-2240},{70240,-2240},{70260,-2240},{70280,-2240},{70300,-2240},{70320,-2240},{70340,-2240},{70360,-2240},{70380,-2240},{70400,-2240},{70420,-2240},{70440,-2240},{70460,-2240},{70480,-2240},{70500,-2240},{70520,-2240},{70540,-2240},{70560,-2240},{70580,-2240},{70600,-2240},{70620,-2240},{70640,-2240},{70660,-2240},{70680,-2240},{70700,-2240},{70720,-2240},{70740,-2240},{70760,-2240},{70780,-2240},{70800,-2240},{70820,-2240},{70840,-2240},{70860,-2240},{70880,-2240},{70900,-2240},{70920,-2240},{70940,-2240},{70960,-2240},{70980,-2240},{71000,-2240},{71020,-2240},{71040,-2240},{71060,-2240},{71080,-2240},{71100,-2240},{71120,-2240},{71140,-2240},{71160,-2240},{71180,-2240},{71200,-2240},{71220,-2240},{71240,-2240},{71260,-2240},{71280,-2240},{71300,-2240},{71320,-2240},{71340,-2240},{71360,-2240},{71380,-2240},{71400,-2240},{71420,-2240},{71440,-2240},{71460,-2240},{71480,-2240},{71500,-2240},{71520,-2240},{71540,-2240},{71560,-2240},{71580,-2240},{71600,-2240},{71620,-2240},{71640,-2240},{71660,-2240},{71680,-2240},{71700,-2240},{71720,-2240},{71740,-2240},{71760,-2240},{71780,-2240},{71800,-2240},{71820,-2240},{71840,-2240},{71860,-2240},{71880,-2240},{71900,-2240},{71920,-2240},{71940,-2240},{71960,-2240},{71980,-2240},{72000,-2240},{72020,-2240},{72040,-2240},{72060,-2240},{72080,-2240},{72100,-2240},{72120,-2240},{72140,-2240},{72160,-2240},{72180,-2240},{72200,-2240},{72220,-2240},{72240,-2240},{72260,-2240},{72280,-2240},{72300,-2240},{72320,-2240},{72340,-2240}};

curve2= {{20,-27980},{80,-27980},{140,-27980},{200,-27980},{260,-27980},{320,-27980},{380,-27980},{440,-27980},{500,-27980},{560,-27980},{620,-27980},{680,-27980},{740,-27980},{800,-27980},{860,-27980},{920,-27980},{980,-27980},{1040,-27980},{1100,-27960},{1160,-27960},{1220,-27960},{1280,-27960},{1340,-27960},{1400,-27960},{1460,-27960},{1520,-27960},{1580,-27960},{1640,-27960},{1700,-27960},{1760,-27960},{1820,-27960},{1880,-27940},{1940,-27940},{2000,-27940},{2060,-27940},{2120,-27940},{2180,-27940},{2240,-27940},{2300,-27940},{2360,-27940},{2420,-27940},{2480,-27940},{2540,-27940},{2600,-27940},{2660,-27920},{2720,-27920},{2780,-27920},{2840,-27920},{2900,-27920},{2960,-27920},{3020,-27920},{3080,-27920},{3140,-27920},{3200,-27920},{3260,-27920},{3320,-27920},{3380,-27920},{3440,-27920},{3500,-27900},{3560,-27900},{3620,-27900},{3680,-27900},{3740,-27900},{3800,-27900},{3860,-27900},{3920,-27900},{3980,-27900},{4040,-27900},{4100,-27900},{4160,-27900},{4220,-27900},{4280,-27900},{4340,-27900},{4400,-27900},{4460,-27900},{4520,-27900},{4580,-27900},{4640,-27900},{4700,-27880},{4760,-27880},{4820,-27880},{4880,-27880},{4940,-27880},{5000,-27880},{5060,-27880},{5120,-27880},{5180,-27880},{5240,-27880},{5300,-27880},{5360,-27880},{5420,-27880},{5480,-27880},{5540,-27880},{5600,-27880},{5660,-27880},{5720,-27880},{5780,-27880},{5840,-27880},{5900,-27860},{5960,-27860},{6020,-27860},{6080,-27860},{6140,-27860},{6200,-27860},{6260,-27860},{6320,-27860},{6380,-27860},{6440,-27860},{6500,-27860},{6560,-27860},{6620,-27860},{6680,-27860},{6740,-27860},{6800,-27860},{6860,-27860},{6920,-27860},{6980,-27860},{7040,-27860},{7100,-27840},{7160,-27840},{7220,-27840},{7280,-27840},{7340,-27820},{7400,-27820},{7460,-27820},{7520,-27800},{7580,-27800},{7640,-27780},{7700,-27780},{7760,-27780},{7820,-27760},{7880,-27760},{7940,-27760},{8000,-27740},{8060,-27740},{8120,-27720},{8180,-27720},{8240,-27720},{8300,-27700},{8360,-27700},{8420,-27680},{8480,-27680},{8540,-27680},{8600,-27660},{8660,-27660},{8720,-27660},{8780,-27640},{8840,-27640},{8900,-27620},{8960,-27620},{9020,-27620},{9080,-27600},{9140,-27600},{9200,-27600},{9260,-27580},{9320,-27580},{9380,-27560},{9440,-27560},{9500,-27560},{9560,-27540},{9620,-27540},{9680,-27520},{9740,-27520},{9800,-27500},{9860,-27500},{9920,-27480},{9980,-27460},{10040,-27460},{10100,-27440},{10160,-27420},{10220,-27400},{10280,-27400},{10340,-27380},{10400,-27360},{10460,-27360},{10520,-27340},{10580,-27320},{10640,-27300},{10700,-27300},{10760,-27280},{10820,-27260},{10880,-27260},{10940,-27240},{11000,-27220},{11060,-27200},{11120,-27200},{11180,-27180},{11240,-27160},{11300,-27160},{11360,-27140},{11420,-27120},{11480,-27100},{11540,-27100},{11600,-27080},{11660,-27060},{11720,-27060},{11780,-27040},{11840,-27020},{11900,-27000},{11960,-27000},{12020,-26980},{12080,-26960},{12140,-26960},{12200,-26940},{12260,-26920},{12320,-26900},{12380,-26900},{12440,-26880},{12500,-26860},{12560,-26840},{12620,-26840},{12680,-26820},{12740,-26800},{12800,-26800},{12860,-26780},{12920,-26760},{12980,-26740},{13040,-26740},{13100,-26720},{13160,-26700},{13220,-26680},{13280,-26680},{13340,-26660},{13400,-26640},{13460,-26640},{13520,-26620},{13580,-26600},{13640,-26580},{13700,-26580},{13760,-26560},{13820,-26540},{13880,-26520},{13940,-26520},{14000,-26500},{14060,-26480},{14120,-26460},{14180,-26460},{14240,-26440},{14300,-26420},{14360,-26420},{14420,-26400},{14480,-26380},{14540,-26360},{14600,-26360},{14660,-26340},{14720,-26320},{14780,-26300},{14840,-26300},{14900,-26280},{14960,-26260},{15020,-26240},{15080,-26240},{15140,-26220},{15200,-26200},{15260,-26200},{15320,-26180},{15380,-26160},{15440,-26140},{15500,-26140},{15560,-26120},{15620,-26100},{15680,-26080},{15740,-26080},{15800,-26060},{15860,-26040},{15920,-26040},{15980,-26020},{16040,-26000},{16100,-25980},{16160,-25980},{16220,-25960},{16280,-25940},{16340,-25920},{16400,-25920},{16460,-25900},{16520,-25880},{16580,-25860},{16640,-25860},{16700,-25840},{16760,-25820},{16820,-25800},{16880,-25780},{16940,-25760},{17000,-25720},{17060,-25700},{17120,-25680},{17180,-25660},{17240,-25620},{17300,-25600},{17360,-25580},{17420,-25560},{17480,-25520},{17540,-25500},{17600,-25480},{17660,-25460},{17720,-25420},{17780,-25400},{17840,-25380},{17900,-25360},{17960,-25320},{18020,-25300},{18080,-25280},{18140,-25240},{18200,-25220},{18260,-25200},{18320,-25180},{18380,-25140},{18440,-25120},{18500,-25100},{18560,-25080},{18620,-25040},{18680,-25020},{18740,-25000},{18800,-24980},{18860,-24940},{18920,-24920},{18980,-24900},{19040,-24880},{19100,-24840},{19160,-24820},{19220,-24800},{19280,-24780},{19340,-24740},{19400,-24720},{19460,-24700},{19520,-24660},{19580,-24640},{19640,-24620},{19700,-24600},{19760,-24560},{19820,-24540},{19880,-24520},{19940,-24500},{20000,-24460},{20060,-24440},{20120,-24420},{20180,-24400},{20240,-24360},{20300,-24340},{20360,-24320},{20420,-24300},{20480,-24260},{20540,-24240},{20600,-24220},{20660,-24180},{20720,-24160},{20780,-24140},{20840,-24120},{20900,-24080},{20960,-24060},{21020,-24040},{21080,-24020},{21140,-23980},{21200,-23960},{21260,-23940},{21320,-23920},{21380,-23880},{21440,-23860},{21500,-23840},{21560,-23820},{21620,-23780},{21680,-23760},{21740,-23740},{21800,-23720},{21860,-23680},{21920,-23660},{21980,-23640},{22040,-23620},{22100,-23600},{22160,-23580},{22220,-23560},{22280,-23540},{22340,-23520},{22400,-23500},{22460,-23460},{22520,-23440},{22580,-23420},{22640,-23400},{22700,-23380},{22760,-23360},{22820,-23340},{22880,-23320},{22940,-23300},{23000,-23260},{23060,-23240},{23120,-23220},{23180,-23200},{23240,-23180},{23300,-23160},{23360,-23140},{23420,-23120},{23480,-23100},{23540,-23080},{23600,-23040},{23660,-23020},{23720,-23000},{23780,-22980},{23840,-22960},{23900,-22940},{23960,-22920},{24020,-22900},{24080,-22880},{24140,-22840},{24200,-22820},{24260,-22800},{24320,-22800},{24380,-22800},{24440,-22780},{24500,-22780},{24560,-22780},{24620,-22760},{24680,-22760},{24740,-22760},{24800,-22760},{24860,-22740},{24920,-22740},{24980,-22740},{25040,-22720},{25100,-22720},{25160,-22720},{25220,-22720},{25280,-22700},{25340,-22700},{25400,-22700},{25460,-22680},{25520,-22680},{25580,-22680},{25640,-22680},{25700,-22660},{25760,-22660},{25820,-22660},{25880,-22640},{25940,-22640},{26000,-22640},{26060,-22620},{26120,-22620},{26180,-22620},{26240,-22620},{26300,-22600},{26360,-22600},{26420,-22600},{26480,-22580},{26540,-22580},{26600,-22580},{26660,-22580},{26720,-22560},{26780,-22560},{26840,-22560},{26900,-22540},{26960,-22540},{27020,-22540},{27080,-22520},{27140,-22520},{27200,-22520},{27260,-22520},{27320,-22500},{27380,-22500},{27440,-22500},{27500,-22480},{27560,-22480},{27620,-22480},{27680,-22500},{27740,-22500},{27800,-22520},{27860,-22520},{27920,-22540},{27980,-22540},{28040,-22560},{28100,-22580},{28160,-22580},{28220,-22600},{28280,-22600},{28340,-22620},{28400,-22640},{28460,-22640},{28520,-22660},{28580,-22660},{28640,-22680},{28700,-22680},{28760,-22700},{28820,-22720},{28880,-22720},{28940,-22740},{29000,-22740},{29060,-22760},{29120,-22780},{29180,-22780},{29240,-22800},{29300,-22800},{29360,-22820},{29420,-22820},{29480,-22840},{29540,-22860},{29600,-22860},{29660,-22880},{29720,-22880},{29780,-22900},{29840,-22920},{29900,-22920},{29960,-22940},{30020,-22940},{30080,-22960},{30140,-22960},{30200,-22980},{30260,-23000},{30320,-23000},{30380,-23020},{30440,-23020},{30500,-23040},{30560,-23060},{30620,-23060},{30680,-23080},{30740,-23080},{30800,-23100},{30860,-23100},{30920,-23120},{30980,-23140},{31040,-23140},{31100,-23160},{31160,-23160},{31220,-23180},{31280,-23200},{31340,-23200},{31400,-23220},{31460,-23220},{31520,-23240},{31580,-23240},{31640,-23260},{31700,-23280},{31760,-23280},{31820,-23300},{31880,-23320},{31940,-23320},{32000,-23340},{32060,-23360},{32120,-23380},{32180,-23380},{32240,-23400},{32300,-23420},{32360,-23420},{32420,-23440},{32480,-23460},{32540,-23460},{32600,-23480},{32660,-23500},{32720,-23500},{32780,-23520},{32840,-23540},{32900,-23540},{32960,-23560},{33020,-23580},{33080,-23600},{33140,-23600},{33200,-23620},{33260,-23640},{33320,-23640},{33380,-23660},{33440,-23680},{33500,-23680},{33560,-23700},{33620,-23720},{33680,-23720},{33740,-23740},{33800,-23760},{33860,-23760},{33920,-23780},{33980,-23800},{34040,-23820},{34100,-23820},{34160,-23840},{34220,-23860},{34280,-23860},{34340,-23880},{34400,-23900},{34460,-23900},{34520,-23920},{34580,-23940},{34640,-23940},{34700,-23960},{34760,-23980},{34820,-23980},{34880,-24000},{34940,-24020},{35000,-24020},{35060,-24040},{35120,-24060},{35180,-24080},{35240,-24080},{35300,-24100},{35360,-24120},{35420,-24120},{35480,-24140},{35540,-24160},{35600,-24160},{35660,-24180},{35720,-24200},{35780,-24200},{35840,-24220},{35900,-24240},{35960,-24240},{36020,-24260},{36080,-24280},{36140,-24300},{36200,-24300},{36260,-24320},{36320,-24340},{36380,-24340},{36440,-24360},{36500,-24380},{36560,-24380},{36620,-24400},{36680,-24420},{36740,-24420},{36800,-24440},{36860,-24460},{36920,-24480},{36980,-24500},{37040,-24520},{37100,-24520},{37160,-24540},{37220,-24560},{37280,-24580},{37340,-24600},{37400,-24620},{37460,-24640},{37520,-24640},{37580,-24660},{37640,-24680},{37700,-24700},{37760,-24720},{37820,-24740},{37880,-24760},{37940,-24760},{38000,-24780},{38060,-24800},{38120,-24820},{38180,-24840},{38240,-24860},{38300,-24880},{38360,-24880},{38420,-24900},{38480,-24920},{38540,-24940},{38600,-24960},{38660,-24980},{38720,-25000},{38780,-25000},{38840,-25020},{38900,-25040},{38960,-25040},{39020,-25060},{39080,-25060},{39140,-25080},{39200,-25100},{39260,-25100},{39320,-25120},{39380,-25120},{39440,-25140},{39500,-25140},{39560,-25160},{39620,-25160},{39680,-25180},{39740,-25180},{39800,-25200},{39860,-25200},{39920,-25220},{39980,-25220},{40040,-25240},{40100,-25240},{40160,-25260},{40220,-25260},{40280,-25280},{40340,-25280},{40400,-25300},{40460,-25300},{40520,-25320},{40580,-25340},{40640,-25340},{40700,-25360},{40760,-25360},{40820,-25380},{40880,-25380},{40940,-25400},{41000,-25400},{41060,-25420},{41120,-25420},{41180,-25440},{41240,-25440},{41300,-25460},{41360,-25460},{41420,-25480},{41480,-25480},{41540,-25500},{41600,-25500},{41660,-25520},{41720,-25520},{41780,-25540},{41840,-25540},{41900,-25560},{41960,-25580},{42020,-25580},{42080,-25600},{42140,-25600},{42200,-25620},{42260,-25620},{42320,-25640},{42380,-25640},{42440,-25660},{42500,-25660},{42560,-25680},{42620,-25680},{42680,-25700},{42740,-25700},{42800,-25720},{42860,-25720},{42920,-25740},{42980,-25740},{43040,-25760},{43100,-25780},{43160,-25780},{43220,-25800},{43280,-25800},{43340,-25820},{43400,-25840},{43460,-25840},{43520,-25860},{43580,-25860},{43640,-25880},{43700,-25880},{43760,-25900},{43820,-25920},{43880,-25920},{43940,-25940},{44000,-25940},{44060,-25960},{44120,-25960},{44180,-25980},{44240,-26000},{44300,-26000},{44360,-26020},{44420,-26020},{44480,-26040},{44540,-26040},{44600,-26060},{44660,-26080},{44720,-26080},{44780,-26100},{44840,-26100},{44900,-26120},{44960,-26120},{45020,-26140},{45080,-26160},{45140,-26160},{45200,-26180},{45260,-26180},{45320,-26200},{45380,-26200},{45440,-26220},{45500,-26240},{45560,-26240},{45620,-26260},{45680,-26260},{45740,-26280},{45800,-26280},{45860,-26280},{45920,-26280},{45980,-26280},{46040,-26300},{46100,-26300},{46160,-26300},{46220,-26300},{46280,-26300},{46340,-26300},{46400,-26300},{46460,-26320},{46520,-26320},{46580,-26320},{46640,-26320},{46700,-26320},{46760,-26320},{46820,-26320},{46880,-26340},{46940,-26340},{47000,-26340},{47060,-26340},{47120,-26340},{47180,-26340},{47240,-26360},{47300,-26360},{47360,-26360},{47420,-26360},{47480,-26380},{47540,-26380},{47600,-26380},{47660,-26400},{47720,-26400},{47780,-26400},{47840,-26400},{47900,-26420},{47960,-26420},{48020,-26420},{48080,-26420},{48140,-26440},{48200,-26440},{48260,-26440},{48320,-26440},{48380,-26460},{48440,-26460},{48500,-26460},{48560,-26460},{48620,-26480},{48680,-26480},{48740,-26480},{48800,-26500},{48860,-26500},{48920,-26500},{48980,-26500},{49040,-26520},{49100,-26520},{49160,-26520},{49220,-26520},{49280,-26540},{49340,-26540},{49400,-26540},{49460,-26540},{49520,-26560},{49580,-26560},{49640,-26560},{49700,-26560},{49760,-26580},{49820,-26580},{49880,-26580},{49940,-26600},{50000,-26600},{50060,-26600},{50120,-26600},{50180,-26620},{50240,-26620},{50300,-26620},{50360,-26620},{50420,-26640},{50480,-26640},{50540,-26640},{50600,-26640},{50660,-26660},{50720,-26660},{50780,-26660},{50840,-26680},{50900,-26680},{50960,-26680},{51020,-26680},{51080,-26700},{51140,-26700},{51200,-26700},{51260,-26700},{51320,-26720},{51380,-26720},{51440,-26720},{51500,-26720},{51560,-26740},{51620,-26740},{51680,-26740},{51740,-26740},{51800,-26740},{51860,-26740},{51920,-26740},{51980,-26740},{52040,-26740},{52100,-26740},{52160,-26740},{52220,-26740},{52280,-26740},{52340,-26740},{52400,-26740},{52460,-26740},{52520,-26740},{52580,-26740},{52640,-26740},{52700,-26740},{52760,-26740},{52820,-26740},{52880,-26740},{52940,-26740},{53000,-26740},{53060,-26740},{53120,-26740},{53180,-26740},{53240,-26740},{53300,-26740},{53360,-26740},{53420,-26760},{53480,-26760},{53540,-26760},{53600,-26760},{53660,-26760},{53720,-26760},{53780,-26760},{53840,-26760},{53900,-26760},{53960,-26780},{54020,-26780},{54080,-26780},{54140,-26780},{54200,-26780},{54260,-26780},{54320,-26780},{54380,-26780},{54440,-26800},{54500,-26800},{54560,-26800},{54620,-26800},{54680,-26800},{54740,-26800},{54800,-26800},{54860,-26800},{54920,-26820},{54980,-26820},{55040,-26820},{55100,-26820},{55160,-26820},{55220,-26820},{55280,-26820},{55340,-26820},{55400,-26820},{55460,-26840},{55520,-26840},{55580,-26840},{55640,-26840},{55700,-26840},{55760,-26840},{55820,-26840},{55880,-26840},{55940,-26860},{56000,-26860},{56060,-26860},{56120,-26860},{56180,-26860},{56240,-26860},{56300,-26860},{56360,-26860},{56420,-26860},{56480,-26860},{56540,-26860},{56600,-26860},{56660,-26840},{56720,-26840},{56780,-26840},{56840,-26840},{56900,-26840},{56960,-26840},{57020,-26840},{57080,-26820},{57140,-26820},{57200,-26820},{57260,-26820},{57320,-26820},{57380,-26820},{57440,-26820},{57500,-26800},{57560,-26800},{57620,-26800},{57680,-26800},{57740,-26800},{57800,-26800},{57860,-26800},{57920,-26780},{57980,-26780},{58040,-26780},{58100,-26780},{58160,-26780},{58220,-26780},{58280,-26760},{58340,-26760},{58400,-26760},{58460,-26760},{58520,-26760},{58580,-26760},{58640,-26760},{58700,-26740},{58760,-26740},{58820,-26740},{58880,-26740},{58940,-26740},{59000,-26740},{59060,-26740},{59120,-26720},{59180,-26720},{59240,-26720},{59300,-26720},{59360,-26720},{59420,-26720},{59480,-26720},{59540,-26700},{59600,-26700},{59660,-26700},{59720,-26700},{59780,-26700},{59840,-26700},{59900,-26700},{59960,-26680},{60020,-26680},{60080,-26680},{60140,-26680},{60200,-26680},{60260,-26680},{60320,-26680},{60380,-26660},{60440,-26660},{60500,-26660},{60560,-26640},{60620,-26640},{60680,-26640},{60740,-26640},{60800,-26620},{60860,-26620},{60920,-26620},{60980,-26600},{61040,-26600},{61100,-26600},{61160,-26600},{61220,-26580},{61280,-26580},{61340,-26580},{61400,-26580},{61460,-26560},{61520,-26560},{61580,-26560},{61640,-26540},{61700,-26540},{61760,-26540},{61820,-26540},{61880,-26520},{61940,-26520},{62000,-26520},{62060,-26500},{62120,-26500},{62180,-26500},{62240,-26500},{62300,-26480},{62360,-26480},{62420,-26480},{62480,-26480},{62540,-26460},{62600,-26460},{62660,-26460},{62720,-26440},{62780,-26440},{62840,-26440},{62900,-26440},{62960,-26420},{63020,-26420},{63080,-26420},{63140,-26400},{63200,-26400},{63260,-26400},{63320,-26400},{63380,-26380},{63440,-26380},{63500,-26380},{63560,-26360},{63620,-26360},{63680,-26360},{63740,-26360},{63800,-26340},{63860,-26340},{63920,-26320},{63980,-26320},{64040,-26300},{64100,-26280},{64160,-26280},{64220,-26260},{64280,-26240},{64340,-26240},{64400,-26220},{64460,-26200},{64520,-26180},{64580,-26180},{64640,-26160},{64700,-26140},{64760,-26140},{64820,-26120},{64880,-26100},{64940,-26100},{65000,-26080},{65060,-26060},{65120,-26060},{65180,-26040},{65240,-26020},{65300,-26000},{65360,-26000},{65420,-25980},{65480,-25960},{65540,-25960},{65600,-25940},{65660,-25920},{65720,-25920},{65780,-25900},{65840,-25880},{65900,-25880},{65960,-25860},{66020,-25840},{66080,-25820},{66140,-25820},{66200,-25800},{66260,-25780},{66320,-25780},{66380,-25760},{66440,-25740},{66500,-25740},{66560,-25720},{66620,-25700},{66680,-25700},{66740,-25680},{66800,-25680},{66860,-25660},{66920,-25660},{66980,-25640},{67040,-25640},{67100,-25640},{67160,-25620},{67220,-25620},{67280,-25600},{67340,-25600},{67400,-25580},{67460,-25580},{67520,-25580},{67580,-25580},{67640,-25580},{67700,-25560},{67760,-25560},{67820,-25560},{67880,-25560},{67940,-25560},{68000,-25560},{68060,-25560},{68120,-25540},{68180,-25540},{68240,-25540},{68300,-25540},{68360,-25540},{68420,-25540},{68480,-25540},{68540,-25520},{68600,-25520},{68660,-25520},{68720,-25520},{68780,-25520},{68840,-25520},{68900,-25520},{68960,-25500},{69020,-25500},{69080,-25500},{69140,-25500},{69200,-25500},{69260,-25500},{69320,-25500},{69380,-25480},{69440,-25480},{69500,-25480},{69560,-25480},{69620,-25480},{69680,-25480},{69740,-25460},{69800,-25460},{69860,-25460},{69920,-25460},{69980,-25460},{70040,-25460},{70100,-25460},{70160,-25440},{70220,-25440},{70280,-25440},{70340,-25440},{70400,-25440},{70460,-25440},{70520,-25440},{70580,-25420},{70640,-25420},{70700,-25420},{70760,-25400},{70820,-25380},{70880,-25380},{70940,-25360},{71000,-25340},{71060,-25340},{71120,-25320},{71180,-25300},{71240,-25300},{71300,-25280},{71360,-25260},{71420,-25260},{71480,-25240},{71540,-25220},{71600,-25220},{71660,-25200},{71720,-25180},{71780,-25180},{71840,-25160},{71900,-25140},{71960,-25140},{72020,-25120},{72080,-25100},{72140,-25100},{72200,-25100},{72260,-25100},{72320,-25100}};
```

Comment: Can you fit a line/polynomial curve to the data?

Comment: You can, but there are too many interfaces of unexpected shapes, you may have to fit each one individually, so I guess it might not be very efficient.

Comment: Isn't this a domain specific problem though and not really about _Mathematica_? You need an algorithm/resampling/fitting approach that works and makes sense for your application... the use of _Mathematica_ is rather accidental here. Perhaps [dsp.se] or [physics.se] might be better avenues?

Comment: I am using Mathematica to do the programming, maybe Mathematica has some special and simple mathematical functions to tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you tried things like `Show[ListPlot@curve, 
 ListPlot[Mean /@ GatherBy[curve, #[[2]] &], Joined -> True]]`?

Comment: Thanks, belisarius, just tried, not so good.

Comment: @yanfyon Could you be more specific about how you measure "goodness"?

Comment: If you're using this as a depth-range profile for ray tracing, can't you just keep track of the points where it is not differentiable (the steps) and just skip any ray that falls on it?

Comment: `model = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d;
fit = FindFit[curve, model, {a, b, c, d}, x];
modelf = Function[{x}, Evaluate[model /. fit]]; Show[ListPlot@curve, 
 Plot[{modelf[x]}, {x, 62700, 72300}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]` does this simple cubic polynomial passes your test of goodness?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. It is good, but the interface  is geographically shortened. If I add the end points, it should works and be a practical solution. Thanks, Belisarius.

Comment: Thanks, PlatoManica, but your solution is impractical, it is not natural, bent down at 70000. As I said, there are interfaces of unexpected shapes.

Comment: Also worth trying is `smooth = Most@SortBy[ExponentialMovingAverage[curve, 1/12], Last]~
   Join~{Last@SortBy[curve, Last]};
ListPlot[{curve, smooth}, Joined -> {False, True}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
ListLinePlot[Mean /@ Split[curve2, Last[#1] === Last[#2] &]]
```

Works fine for both datasets.

Comment: Great!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks a lot, shrx.    To be perfect, in case the flat section is very long, that is, the interface is truly flat(like the last plateau shown on the plot), slight adaption might be needed.

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
Show[ListPlot@curve, ListPlot[Mean /@ GatherBy[curve, Last], Joined -> True]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is still not perfect, I tried it on other interfaces with undulations, the result is a mess.

Comment: @yanfyon Instead of making us blindly chase your "hidden goals", why don't you be upfront and also share a dataset with your undulations and what you consider to be a "good result"? If the goodness of the result depends on the output of another function, then please include that as well. Instead, being a blackbox and simply saying that the "result is a mess" is unhelpful for those that are trying to help _you_.

Comment: Sorry, I add another interface with undulations, if the method works on both interfaces, then it works. Thanks a lot for all of your efforts.

Comment: @yanfyon Your second curve shows completely different features. It's another kind of problem

Comment: Actually, if magnified and look in detail, the second curve has same kind of step artificials somewhere as the first curve.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like the long flat plateau be partially kept because it might be true flatness, so I like this result better(blue curve is by shrx's way, red curve is my "improvement"):

[image]

Here is my code referring to shrx's answer:
(I don't like the do loop, how can it be avoided?)

```
temp1 = Split[curve3, Last[#1] === Last[#2] &];
temp2 = {};
Do[ If[Length@temp1[[i]] > 50, 
  temp2 = Join[temp2, Partition[temp1[[i]], 30]], 
  temp2 = Join[temp2, {temp1[[i]]}]], {i, 1, Length@temp1}]
ListLinePlot[Mean /@ temp2, PlotStyle -> Red];
```